# How to write mathematical equations with automatic line numbers in Stack exchange editor

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Here is the equations with automatic line numbers obatined in texstudio [image]

How can I write same in latex editor in Mathstackexchange?

Comment: Not sure its possible without just recreating something similar. MathJax won't let you use many things that refer to or depend on page dimensions and margins. You can't use things like `/hspace` or `\vfill` since the display dimensions and margins are not actually fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This will work . But idea of making it automatic would be more convenient than adding "\tag" in every line \begin{align}
  x \tag 1\\
   y \tag 2\\
  z \tag 3 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please replace the image with a code block for the sake of future readers.

Comment: I don't want MathJax people to work on this. IIRC that would lead to problems when there are several answers using the feature. At least in the past we were told not use private TeX definitions unless we wrap them inside a group, because the definitions would still be in effect in the answers after yours. Here that might similarly result in the next guys equation numbering continuing from where yours ended, and chaos would result. MathJax is not intended to be exactly the same as LaTeX. As long as the most common gadgets work, I am fine using it.

Comment: It may be just me, but I rarely need many equations numbered. There are other ways of referring to them, and to most readers figuring out the flow is non-problematic anyway.